# pyqt import problem

Tags: python, pyqt, dcop

I am having some trouble doing this in Python:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from dcopext import DCOPClient, DCOPApp
```

The traceback I get is

```
from dcopext import DCOPClient, DCOPApp 
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/dcopext.py", line 35, in <module>
from dcop    import DCOPClient
RuntimeError: the qt and PyQt4.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class
```

I tried switching the imports, importing dcopext later in the file, but none worked.
Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:** I have narrowed it down to one problem: I am using dcopext which internally uses qt3, but I want it to use PyQt4.

Answer (score 1):

The `dcopext` module is part of [PyKDE3](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pykde/intro), the Python bindings for KDE3 which uses Qt 3.x, while you're using PyQt/Qt 4.x.

You need to upgrade to [PyKDE4](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python/Using_PyKDE_4), now released as part of KDE itself, unless you want to target KDE 3 in which case you need a corresponding old version of Qt and PyQt (3.x).

Comment: Hi dF, thanks for your help. I am running on KDE3.5, having qt4 installed and trying to use PyQt4 with dcop. Is there a way to do that?